# Fetching posts using Facebook4j

Tags: facebook

Hi I am trying to get specific columns from a post on facebook page and then finally get them output in a text file with formatting. This is what i tried so far

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray; 
import net.sf.json.JSONObject; 
import facebook4j.Facebook; 
import facebook4j.FacebookException;
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory; 
import facebook4j.Post;
import facebook4j.Reading;
import facebook4j.ResponseList;
import facebook4j.conf.Configuration; 
import facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder; 

public class fB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FacebookException { 
        // Make the configuration builder 
        ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
        confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true); 
        // Set application id, secret key and access token 
        confBuilder.setOAuthAppId(""); 
        confBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret(""); 
        confBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken("");


        // Set permission 
        confBuilder.setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_stream, id, name, first_name, last_name, generic"); 
        confBuilder.setUseSSL(true); 
        confBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true); 


        // Create configuration object 
        Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build(); 

        // Create facebook instance 
        FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(configuration); 
        Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance();

        try { 
            // Get facebook posts 
            String results = getFacebookPosts(facebook);
            //String responce = stringToJson(results); 



            // Create file and write to the file 
            File file = new File("C:\\Facebook\\test.txt"); 
            if (!file.exists()) 
            { 
                file.createNewFile(); 
            }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); 
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(results); 
                bw.close(); 
                System.out.println("Writing complete"); 

            } catch (IOException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
        }



public static String getFacebookPosts(Facebook facebook) throws FacebookException { 
    // Get posts for a particular search 
    ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.getFeed("Rebook");
    //System.out.println(facebook.getId());
    //System.out.println(facebook.getName());
    //System.out.println(facebook.getFeed());

    return results.toString(); 
    } 

public static String stringToJson(String data) 
{ // Create JSON object 
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(data); 
    JSONArray message = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("message"); 
    System.out.println("Message : "+message); 
    return "Done"; 
    }

}
```

This is giving me all the columns but I am only interested in ID,Message and created date. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Only one of the permissions you are asking for actually exists. You need to ask for the _fields_ you want, when making the API request. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields (How/if that is possible using facebook4j, you’ll have to find out yourself, it should be in the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify how you want data returned from the Facebook API, you need to use the [Reading class](https://facebook4j.github.io/javadoc/facebook4j/Reading.html). For example, you can construct a Reading that specifies the fields you want returned like this:

```
Reading reading = new Reading().fields("id", "created_time", "message");
facebook.getFeed("Rebook", reading);
```

You can find out more in facebook4j's official [documentation](https://facebook4j.github.io/en/code-examples.html#reading).

Comment: Thank you so much.. I am not getting in Notepad, can you please suggest me how can i get it to excel with some formatting

Comment: Thank you so much.. I am now getting in Notepad, can you please suggest me how can i get it to excel with some formatting

Comment: You can use a CSV writing library ([e.g. Commons CSV from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)) to write the data to CSV and then open it in Excel.